# Azure Kusto Java SDK get all columns of query results

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kusto-java-sdk

I'm using the [Azure Kusto Java SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-java) v2.0.1 with Scala over Java8.

I'm executing some query:

```
val query = " ... "
val tenantId = " ... "
val queryResponse = client.execute(tenantId, query)
val queryResponseResults = queryResponse.getPrimaryResults
```

I want to convert the given data structure to JSON eventually, so I want to get all columns, but I can't seem to find some kind of `getColumns`.

While debugging I see the object (`KustoResultSetTable`) has fields `columnsAsArray` (which is exactly what I want) and `columns` - but they are private and I didn't find any getters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A getter will be added in the next version

Comment: Do you have a source for that? A timeline for that version?

Comment: It will be this week

Comment: version 2.0.2 supports it